# Add items to comboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

When I have added a comboBox to the WPF window, how do I add items to the comboBox? Int the XAML code for the design or in NameOfWindow.xaml.cs file?

Comment: WPF has one great feature for that. Its called "Databinding". For starting with WPF [this](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/) should help you.

Comment: ahem.. WinForms had data binding too :)

Comment: I don't mention the opposite. I just said that WPFs Databinding is a great Feature :)

Answer (score 76):

**CASE 1 - You don't have a data-source:**

You can just populate the `ComboBox` with static values as follows -

1. from XAML:

```xml
<ComboBox Height="23" Name="comboBox1" Width="120">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Alice"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Bob"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Charlie"/>
</ComboBox>
```

2. from CodeBehind - 1:

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Alice");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Bob");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Charlie");
}
```

3. from CodeBehind - 2:

```cs
// insert item at specified index of populated ComboBox
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Insert(2, "Alice");
    comboBox1.Items.Insert(5, "Bob");
    comboBox1.Items.Insert(8, "Charlie");
}
```

**CASE 2 - You have a data-source, and the items never get changed:**

You can use the data-source to populate the `ComboBox`. *Any* `IEnumerable` type can be used as a data-source. You can -

1. bind the `ItemsSource` property in `XAML` to the data-source like -

```xml
<!-- MyDataSource is an IEnumerable type property in ViewModel -->
<ComboBox Height="23" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSource}" />
```

2. assign data-source to the `ItemsSource` property in the code-behind, like -

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie" };
}
```

**CASE 3 - You have a data-source, and the items might get changed**

1. You ***should*** use an `ObservableCollection<T>` as the data-source
2. You ***should*** bind the `ItemsSource` property in `XAML` to the data-source (as shown above)
3. You ***can*** assign data-source to the `ItemsSource` property in the code-behind (as shown above)

Using an `ObservableCollection<T>` ensures that whenever an item is added to or removed from the data-source, the change will reflect immediately on the UI. It's up to you how you populate the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 41):

Its better to build [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) and take advantage of it

```
public ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
list.Add("a");
list.Add("b");
list.Add("c");
this.cbx.ItemsSource = list;
```

cbx is comobobox name

Also Read : [Difference between List, ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/8e9ef79d-e6cd-4cca-9934-24410dea522e)

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
string[] str = new string[] {"Foo", "Bar"};

myComboBox.ItemsSource = str;
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

OR

```
foreach (string s in str)
    myComboBox.Items.Add(s);

myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Nice it's working well! But if I want like name or a headline for the combobox like "Your options:", then I guess I just add that first in the array, but when a selection is made, I check so that index 0 isn't activated!? Or is there a better way?

Comment: No, I get "your options" twice!? It's on the "button" but it's also in the list that drops down hen I click on the combobox!

Comment: Is there a way to solve this? I want a name on the button and when I press on the button, I want items to be drop down, and not the name of the button? Preciate if this could be done!

Answer (score 4):

You can fill it from XAML or from .cs. There are few ways to fill controls with data. It would be best for You to read more about WPF technology, it allows to do many things in many ways, depending on Your needs. It's more important to choose method based on Your project needs. You can start [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-combobox/). It's an easy article about creating combobox, and filling it with some data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to perform this task. Here is a simple one:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Demo1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     x:Name="TestWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="773">

<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Red" Margin="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="spTopNav">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboBox1" MinWidth="120"> <!-- Notice we have used x:Name to identify the object that we want to operate upon.-->
            <!--
                <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
            -->
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Orange" Margin="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="spBottomNav">
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Height="30" Foreground="White">Left Docked StackPanel 2</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel MinWidth="200" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Teal" Margin="2" x:Name="StackPanelLeft">
        <TextBlock  Foreground="White">Bottom Docked StackPanel Left</TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Yellow" MinWidth="150" Margin="2" x:Name="StackPanelRight"></StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="410" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click"/>


</DockPanel>

</Window>
```

Next, we have the C# code:

```
    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem(); // Create example instance of our desired type.
        Type type1 = cboBoxItem.GetType();
        object cboBoxItemInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type1); // Construct an instance of that type.
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            string newName = "stringExample" + i.ToString();
           // Generate the objects from our list of strings.
            ComboBoxItem item = this.CreateComboBoxItem((ComboBoxItem)cboBoxItemInstance, "nameExample_" + newName, newName);
            cboBox1.Items.Add(item); // Add each newly constructed item to our NAMED combobox.
        }
    }
    private ComboBoxItem CreateComboBoxItem(ComboBoxItem myCbo, string content, string name)
    {
        Type type1 = myCbo.GetType();
        ComboBoxItem instance = (ComboBoxItem)Activator.CreateInstance(type1);
        // Here, we're using reflection to get and set the properties of the type.
        PropertyInfo Content = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Content", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        PropertyInfo Name = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        this.SetProperty<ComboBoxItem, String>(Content, instance, content);
        this.SetProperty<ComboBoxItem, String>(Name, instance, name);

        return instance;
        //PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperties(rb1);
    }
```

Note: This is using reflection.
If you'd like to learn more about the basics of reflection and why you might want to use it, this is a great introductory article:

- [An Introduction to Reflection in .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206412/Reflection-An-Introduction-to-Reflection-in-NE)

If you'd like to learn more about *how* you might use reflection with WPF specifically, here are some resources:

- [Reflection for WPF Rockstars](https://loosexaml.wordpress.com/reflection-for-wpf-rockstars/)
- [Use the Power of Reflection to Create and Manipulate Managed Objects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2015/12/30/use-the-power-of-reflection-to-create-and-manipulate-managed-objects/)

And if you want to *massively* speed up the performance of reflection, it's best to use IL to do that, like this:

- [Fast version of the ActivatorCreateInstance method using IL](http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/08/Fast-version-of-the-ActivatorCreateInstance-method-using-IL.aspx)
- [Fast Dynamic Property and Field Accessors](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14560/Fast-Dynamic-Property-Field-Accessors)

Answer (score 0):

I think `comboBox1.Items.Add("X");` will add `string` to ComboBox, instead of `ComboBoxItem`.

The right solution is

```
ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
item.Content = "A";
comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score -1):

With OleDBConnection -> connect to Oracle

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=oracle;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=system;Password=**********;Unicode=True";

            OleDbCommand comd1 = new OleDbCommand("select name from table", con);
            OleDbDataReader DR = comd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (DR.Read())
            {
                comboBox_delete.Items.Add(DR[0]);
            }
            con.Close();
```

That's all :)