# ComboBox cannot display new value added

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added a new value into my combobox and it should be displayed based on what I have in my database. But unfortunately, the new value does not display out. Below are my codes.

```
string dbConn = "Data     Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\SONY\\Desktop\\FinalYearProject\\FinalYearProject\\bin\\Debug\\housewife.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

void fill_Combo() { 
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn);
       try {
           conn.Open();
           string query = "Select * From Food";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read()) {
                string name = dr.GetString(1);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
            }
            conn.Close();
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Do you call the fill_Combo() method after you insert the new item in the database?

Comment: Please remove all this horrible SQL string code from code behind, create a proper Data Access Layer, and learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: Are you adding your records to the .mdf file which is in bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an observable collection as the data source and binding to that collection.  See [Add items to comboBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878217/add-items-to-combobox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try something like this, hope it helps

```
string dbConn = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\SONY\\Desktop\\FinalYearProject\\FinalYear Project\\bin\\Debug\\housewife.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

void fill_Combo() { 
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn);
   try {
       conn.Open();
       string query = "Select * From Food";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds)
        combobox1.DataSourse = ds;
        combobox1.DisplayMember = "fieldname";
        combobox1.ValueMember = "fieldname";
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```