# ComboBox writing Words in a TXT

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Let me show you what I have in my code :

```
public List<String> listQuality = new List<string>();
public int qualityChoose;

InitializeComponent();

listQuality.Add("Fastest");
listQuality.Add("Fast");
listQuality.Add("Simple");
listQuality.Add("Good");
listQuality.Add("Beautiful");
listQuality.Add("Fantastic");

foreach (String item in listQuality)
{
    listQualityy.Items.Add(item);
}

string textWriteQuality;
textWriteQuality = "-screen-quality " + qualityChoose + Environment.NewLine;

File.AppendAllText(@"./arguments.txt", textWriteQuality);
```

But ofc it doesn't work, I think the problem is the "init" but i'm not sure i'm noob at coding it's my first program (Yeah i repeat it again xd)

I have skipped some other code that are useless for the question - I think -

Comment: Are  you receiving any error or exception?

Comment: Why this code? foreach (String item in listQuality)
{
    listQualityy.Items.Add(item);
}

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What is "qualityChoose" set to? If it is an issue with adding items to a ComboBox - see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878217/add-items-to-combobox-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks for all your reply, by "it doesn't work" I mean instead of writing "Fastest" or "fast" etc, it was writing 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question isn't very understandable, by the way you can do something like this example

xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding listQuality}" SelectedItem="{Binding qualityChoose}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Save" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
```

codebehind:

```
public List<Tuple<int, String>> listQuality { get; set; }
        public Tuple<int, String> qualityChoose { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listQuality = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
            listQuality.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(0, "Fastest"));
            listQuality.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Fast"));
            listQuality.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Simple"));
            listQuality.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Good"));
            listQuality.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(4, "Beautiful"));
            listQuality.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(5, "Fantastic"));

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int quality = qualityChoose.Item1;
        }
```

when you click the button "Save" in *qualityChoose.Item1* there's your value

**EDIT**

instead using a tuple you can use a List< string > like in your question, modify xaml like this:

```
...
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding listQuality}" SelectedIndex="{Binding selIndex}">
...
```

and in codebehind add "selIndex" property:

```
public int selIndex { get; set; }
```

in this property there's the index of the selected string. 
this is easier but you can't decide the value of qualities.